# getx RxMap flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Could you help me, use package getx, when I use RxMap with the add method it does not let me add to the RxMap, check the getx package, but the add method is not in the rxmap
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do like this using RxMap, Instead of add use like this

```
final mapObject = RxMap();
mapObject['test'] = 'item';
print(mapObject);
```

Output:

```
{test: item}
```

So, In your case

```
void addMapItem(){
mapItems[DateTime.now().toString()] = DateTime.now().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this use full to declare it as literal

```
class FooController extends GetxController {
   final data = <String, dynamic>{}.obs;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).